# Async job in facebook insights API not picking up

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights

I'm creating async job for fetching device performance report at campaign level using /insights endpoint. After getting the async job_id, when i'm polling for completion, following is the response for some of the campaign's async_job_id:

`{"id":"<<async_job_id>>","account_id":"<<account_id>>","time_ref":1490218806,"async_status":"Job Not Started","async_percent_completion":0,"date_start":"2017-02-21","date_stop":"2017-03-22"}`

- This is the response i'm receiving for some async jobs for duration of 1-2 hours. Post that job is getting completed.
- Remaining async jobs gets completed in about 1-2 minutes.

Any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to affect this behaviour as the time taken for an async job to complete is based on many factors.

If you need insights data returned immediately, you should try to request smaller data sets, and not use async jobs.